# Is there a handler function detect that Action.ShowCard button is clicked in Adaptive Cards

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We have an adaptive card which has a Action of the type Action.ShowCard. On click of this button we show some fields and one action of the type Action.Execute.

We want to perform api call when the ShowCard button is clicked to get some properties.
Is there a way or a handler function to detect that Action.ShowCard is clicked in Microsoft Adaptive Card.
Below is the reference schema json for Show Card

```
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "ShowCard",
            "style": "destructive",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "test",
                        "isRequired": true,
                        "label": "test field"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Execute",
                        "verb": "cancelAction",
                        "style": "destructive",
                        "title": "Cancel",
                        "data": {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
```

Comment: Currently there is no event to detect that Action.ShowCard is clicked on adaptive card.